# Processing variable for mouseWheel

Tags: java, processing

Is there a variable in `Java` or `Processing Java` that stores whether the mouse is scrolling or not? I know in `Processing` there is a `function` but I need a `variable`.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but why wouldn't you create a function like getWheelScroll as a boolean and use the other function to check if the mouse is scrolling? Then you could use the conditional such as if(getWheelScroll() == true)

Comment: @Adamsky The mouseScrolled() function is void.

Comment: @Henry By the way, you shouldn't just delete questions. I had an answer typed out to your other question yesterday right before you deleted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create your own variable and set it inside the `mouseWheel` function.

```
float wheelCount = 0;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
}

void draw() {
   if(wheelCount > 0){
      //do something with the variable

      wheelCount = 0; //reset it so we don't keep getting events
   }

} 

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent event) {
  wheelCount = event.getCount();
}
```

However, note that the `wheelCount` variable will only be valid for a single frame, which is why you should use the event instead.

Comment: What I wanted to keep running code as long as the mouse is scrolled? I would really appreciate some help with that.

Comment: @Henry The mouse scrolling event is not continuous. You get a separate event for each "click" of the mouse scroll wheel. You'll have to set up a timer that "turns off" the mouse wheel after X milliseconds of not receiving a mouseWheel event.